# Sidekiq scheduler to overwrite redis store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, sidekiq

I've never used Sidekiq before, and I'm struggling with the following. I have a worker :

```
# app/workers/my_worker.rb

class MyWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options retry: false

    def perform(s_user)

        user = $client.user_timeline(s_user, exclude_replies: 1,include_rts: 1 ).take(10)
        user.each do |t|
        array_list   = $client.retweeters_of(t.id)
        end
        limited_list = array_list

        array = []
        hash  = {}

        limited_list.each do |g|

            hash = {:key => g.followers_count, :value => g.profile_image_url.to_s}
            array.push(hash)

        end

        array.sort_by! {|h| h[:key]}
        array.reverse!
        final = array.take(10)

        final.each do |h|
            $redis.sadd("#{h[:value]}", "#{h[:key]}")
        end
    end

end
```

I call it as :

```
MyWorker.perform_async(@user)
```

I'm trying to add the resulting array of key-value pairs into a redis db, and get that to be displayed. But the Sidekiq UI declared that all processes fail right after getting into the "busy" queue.

Ideally, I want this worker to run every few hours, and then overwrite the redis store.

Please help.

Comment: How you are invoking this worker?

Comment: by using `MyWorker.perform_async(@user)` in the controller.

Comment: It comes to the default queue first, right? Just set :retry => 2 and see the error log.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and now the sidekiq terminal reports :

`2014-04-20T12:29:38Z 3056 TID-15ikre MyWorker JID-a1a89e3a8f31ddfc61c5b930 INFO: start
2014-04-20T12:30:02Z 3056 TID-15ikre MyWorker JID-a1a89e3a8f31ddfc61c5b930 INFO: fail: 23.995 sec
2014-04-20T12:30:02Z 3056 TID-15ikre WARN: {"retry"=>false, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"MyWorker", "args"=>["dhh"], "jid"=>"a1a89e3a8f31ddfc61c5b930", "enqueued_at"=>1397996978.8628416}
2014-04-20T12:30:02Z 3056 TID-15ikre WARN: undefined local variable or method "array_list" for #<MyWorker:0xa603678 @jid="a1a89e3a8f31ddfc61c5b930">`

Comment: Meaning array_list, which I created in the worker, seems to be "undefined" :(

Comment: what does this `$client` stand for? Please inspect and try to know what you are getting for `user`.

Comment: $client is a global variable to use the Twitter API. 

`config = {
  :consumer_key    => "key_here",
  :consumer_secret => "secret_here",
}

$client = Twitter::REST::Client.new(config)`

Comment: Do you get any values for `user`?

Comment: Yes, the value is the twitter handler that I need to send.

Comment: Since array_list is undefined, it is sure that it is not getting inside the user.each loop and please check it before proceeding

Comment: `user.each do |t|
        array_list   = $client.retweeters_of(t.id)
 end`

But array_list has been declared inside user.each loop

Comment: `limited_list = array_list` this line will break if array_list is undefined and later on following code will also break up.

Comment: array_list is declared as an array of integers, and due to Duck Typing in ruby, limited_list will also take the same datatype and values. How would that break, and what would be an effective alternative to this?

Comment: array_list is defined inside `user.each` loop and as the execution is not getting inside that loop and in the following line, the undefined array_list is being allocated to `limited_list` which is being used further. How can you allocate an undefined variable (array_list) to limited_list? Can you just show the result of the following line, `user = $client.user_timeline(s_user, exclude_replies: 1,include_rts: 1 ).take(10)`

Comment: I'll output the first element of the array since the output would be too large as a comment : 
`- !ruby/object:Twitter::Tweet
  attrs:
    :created_at: Tue Apr 15 16:02:31 +0000 2014
    :id: 456100263448
    :id_str: '4561014368'
    :text: 'Related to the glorification of busy: "Sleep deprivation is not a badge
      of honor", https://t.co/ZJ3OVoJ1eJ'
    :source: <a href="http://itunes/twitter/id409789998?mt=12" rel="nofollow">Twitter
      for Mac</a>
    :truncated: false
    :in_reply_to_status_id: 
    :in_reply_to_status_id_str:`